# react-native-navbar statusbar color not getting changed on android

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am using react-native-navbar, am I doing something wrong? the statusbar color is not changing. It works on iphone but not on android. My code below

```
 <NavigationBar
                  title={{title:'Notifications', tintColor:'yellow'}}
                  tintColor="#ef5350"
                  statusBar={{style: 'light-content',tintColor:'#ef5350'}}
              />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to set this prop to the `StatusBar` component: `backgroundColor='#ef5350'`

As per the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.43/docs/statusbar.html#backgroundcolor)

> [Android] backgroundColor?: $FlowFixMe
>
> The background color of the status bar.

Comment: I am using this library: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-navbar. And in the docs it states to just add tintColor for statusBar to change its color. Again, it works for IOS but not for Android.